# Gift Card Quote Item Prices are NULL in cart related events

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, checkout, event-observer

I want to do some customization when a gift card is added to cart so I have created a module observer with event `checkout_cart_product_add_after`, I am getting the product id, product type on the quote item, but not the price or base price. The product type is `mpgiftcard`

I have to do some price calculations based on the item price but the `$item->getPrice()` and `$item->getBasePrice()` are returning null

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');       
        $productID = $item->getProductId();            

            $price = $item->getPrice();
            $currentCurrencyRate = $this->storemanager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyRate();               
            
            $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/giftcard.log');
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            $logger->info('Product ID: '.$productID);
            $logger->info('Price: '.$price);                
            $logger->info('Product Type: '.$item->getProductType());  
            $logger->info('BasePrice: '. $item->getBasePrice());

            $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );                
            $item->setCustomPrice($price);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below code.

```
$item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
foreach($item  as $_item){
  $product = $_item->getProduct();
  $pdata = $product->getData();
}
```

Comment: The Price of the Product is correct here, but `$item->getProduct()->getSpecialPrice()` returns the incorrect (full) base price instead of the configured lower Special Price here. The only thing that returns the configured Special Price is `$item->getPriceInclTax()` for me.